# How can we create a glossary of popular terms?

Tags: feature-request

I say plasterboard, you say drywall
I say uPVC, you say vinyl... let's call the whole thing off?

Seriously. Should we find a way to create a glossary of DIY-related terms to help bridge the culture gaps between US, UK, Canadian and Australasian usage?

Comment: Make this Community Wiki and then people add terms in an an answer... like I'm about to do...

Comment: Questions that ask users to create a list of answers should be made community wiki. I converted this question.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think the structure is off. Instead of multiple answers with one term each, there should be one answer collaboratively edited with a list of terms and their "translation." (See my answer below as an example.)

Comment: This was a great idea until 5 answers said the same thing... :(

Answer (score 5):

- **Joint Compound** or **Mud** (US) - **Plaster** (UK)
- **Vinyl** (US) - **uPVC** (UK) ?
- **Drywall** (US) - **Sheetrock** (US) - **Plasterboard** (UK)

Comment: Or should this be a table instead?

Comment: +1 to get this at the top of the list so we're only editing a single entry.  I vote for your style since a table would require expanding each time a new country is included.

Answer (score 2):

- **Drywall** (US) (aka 'gypsum board', aka 'wallboard', aka 'sheet rock' (specific brand))
- **Plasterboard** (UK)

related terms:

- **Greenboard** (US): a water resistant variant
- **Blueboard** (US): a variant treated for use as backing for plastering
- **Cementboard** (US): a similar product, used as backing for tiling.

Answer (score 1):

- **Vinyl** (US)
- **uPVC** (UK)

(not sure about this one...)

Answer (score 1):

The question is *how*, no? It seems like tag wikis would be a better place to do this.

Comment: This question was asked around the time the entire tag wiki, tag synonym, etc. system was being put in place.  I agree, explanation of the various synonyms in the wikis is a good way to handle this.

Comment: Eesh. i didn't even notice it was mroe than two years old.

Answer (score 0):

- **Plaster** (UK)
- **Mud** (US)

Comment: I think the term "Plaster" is common enough in the US that anyone would know what you were talking about.  Not sure about the term "Mud" in the UK though.

Comment: Isn't plaster umm... plaster? the stuff that makes a wall (as in "my wall is lath and paster")?  while mud is usually used to refer to joint compound, or whats used to patch drywall.  Are these terms really interchangeable?

Comment: I've never heard it called "mud" here in the US.

Comment: "Mud" is a very common term for "drywall joint compound" and it's much easier to say. It is, however, very different than the plaster used as a skim coat and final finish (prior to paint) that can be applied over taped & mudded drywall.